# Running if condition after all three items are updated

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a list which is supposed to receive values from several hosts periodically and do some operations on these values.

```
List<Integer> loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.1")
                        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

                    loadList.add(0, intLoad1);
                }
                else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.2") 
                        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

                    loadList.add(1, intLoad2);
                }
                else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.3") 
                        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

                    loadList.add(2, intLoad3);
                }

                if (!loadList.isEmpty() && !loadList.contains(null)) {
                    int sum = loadList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
                    System.out.println("---- Sum: "+sum);
                    double averageLoad = ((double) sum) / loadList.size();
                }
```

In my code the 4th `if` condition (I mean `if (!loadList.isEmpty() && !loadList.contains(null))`) will run every time it receives a new value, but I'm trying to change it so that it will run after the end of each period (when all the three elements in the list are updated). I mean I want it to run only when all the three load value are received (so that I will find the average value of the newly received values).

I searched for a solution but I didn't find anything. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you create a separate method that will be called after each value added in the list, and checks if all the 3 values were added in the list... if yes -> you do the average. Or even better, call the method only when you have the 3 values in the current list -> that means that instead of the last if you just check if the list has the 3 elements -> if yes, you do the average.

Comment: @AndreaCalin In each period each of these elements are updated. My current code will find the average between 3 numbers regardless of whether they are updated or not. For example `list = [a1 a2 a3]`, `avg = (a1 + a2 + a3)/3`. Now for example the first element is updated `list = [b1 a2 a3]`, my code will find the average like this `avg = (b1 a2 a3)/3`, but I want it to find the average when all the three elements are updated ( I mean `list = [b1 b2 b3]`)

Comment: Then just use some flags to determine when the 3 values were all updated.

Comment: "when all the three elements in the list are updated" - Instead of `if (!loadList.isEmpty() && !loadList.contains(null)) {...}` check for `if (loadList.size() == 3 {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can add three boolean fields and use them in the last if statement:

```
boolean first = false;
boolean second= false;
boolean third = false;
List<Integer> loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.1") && udp.getPayload() != null) {
    loadList.add(0, intLoad1);
    first = true;
} else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.2") && udp.getPayload() != null) {
    loadList.add(1, intLoad2);
    second = true;
} else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.3") && udp.getPayload() != null) {
    loadList.add(2, intLoad3);
    third = true;
}

if (!loadList.isEmpty() && !loadList.contains(null) && first && second && third) {
    int sum = loadList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    System.out.println("---- Sum: "+sum);
    double averageLoad = ((double) sum) / loadList.size();
    first = false;
    second= false;
    third = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using flags:

```
List<Integer> loadList = new ArrayList<>(3);
boolean first = false;
boolean second = false;
boolean third = false;

if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.1")
        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

    loadList.add(0, intLoad1);
    first = true;
}
else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.2")
        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

    loadList.add(1, intLoad2);
    second = true;
}
else if ((dstIp.toString().equals("10.0.0.3")
        && udp.getPayload() != null) {

    loadList.add(2, intLoad3);
    third = true;
}

if (!loadList.isEmpty() && !loadList.contains(null) && first && second && third) {
    int sum = loadList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    System.out.println("---- Sum: "+sum);
    double averageLoad = ((double) sum) / loadList.size();
    first = false;
    second = false;
    third = false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `List<Future>` and push all the three values into that list.
Then wait for all of those to be complete and do the average.

that would look roughly like below:

```
List<Future<Integer>> futures= new ArrayList<>();
futures.push(1); // 2,3 as well
// now that we have all the future values
for(Future currFuture:futures) {
    if(!currFuture.isDone()) currFuture.get();
}
// now perform average
int sum = 0;
for(Integer value: futures) {
  sum+= value;
}
System.out.println("avg is ", sum/values.length);
```

Syntax could go wrong a bit since I haven't written any java code in recent times. Please feel free to edit as required